# How should I style an element with border, border-radius, and overflow:auto?

Tags: css

I'm styling a list that, to be consistent with peer elements, needs to be in an element with round-cornered borders.  The list may or may not be tall enough to cause vertical scrollbars.

If I style the list with fully rounded corners, the scrollbar obscures the corner rounding, which looks broken:

```css
ul {
  border: 2px solid grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 8em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

If I remove the right-side corner rounding, the scrollbar looks correct when the present:

```css
ul {
  border: 2px solid grey;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 8em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

but this means the element looks inconsistent when the list is too short to scroll.  I can set `overflow-y:scroll` instead of auto, but I'd prefer to avoid always showing the bar.  Is there any way to style this so that an element with no overflow has rounded corners, but an element with a scrollbar does not?  (Other solutions welcome!)

Comment: You are using chrome, right? First example works in firefox.

Comment: I hadn't even thought to check.  It's broken in Chrome but also IE and Edge.  It's cool that Firefox handles this well (especially considering their hard-line stance against customizing scrollbar appearance) but I'd really like something that looks consistently good on any platform.

Answer (score 4):

You could wrap a `div` around the `ul` element. Then apply the `border-radius` on the `div`. To hide the scollbar overflowing the corners apply `overflow: hidden` to it.

```css
div {
    border: 2px solid grey;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 8em;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I saw another question with a similar suggestion, but for certain combinations of border color and radius this can make the scrollbar look pretty weird IMHO.  I will keep this in mind but would still prefer something that "fixes" the border to play nice with the scrollbar, rather than shoehorning the scrollbar into the existing border.

Comment: Perhaps use a custom scrollbar? Like http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution I came up with:
If the div is larger than 150px, it adds the class `rounded` to the `ul` and the right borders aren't rounded.
The thing with this is, that you *have* to use pixels as a unit in `max-height`
**EDIT:** I added a little button, that adds a list item, so you can see the effect.
**EDIT 2:** Edited my pen, so you can use `vh` instead of pixels. Just change the `0.4` in the `var containerHeight` (0.4 = 40vh)

```js
var containerHeight = $(window).height() * 0.4;

$('button').click(function(){
    $('.listContainer').append('<li>Item</li>');
    if ($('.listContainer').outerHeight() >= containerHeight) {
       $('.listContainer').addClass("notrounded");
    }
});
```

```css
ul{
border: 2px solid grey;
border-radius: 10px;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
max-height: 40vh;
}
ul.notrounded{
border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="listContainer">
<li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li>
</ul>
<button>add list item</button>
```

Comment: @RichardMauritz Why this doesn't answer the question? Take a look at the bottom 2 lines of the initial question. "_Is there any way to style this so that an element with no overflow has rounded corners, but an element with a scrollbar does not?_". That's exactly what I did. If the div got an overflow, there aren't rounded corners and if there isn't, there are rounded corners.

Comment: You're right, i didnt see that part. Sorry, my bad.

Comment: I was thinking about something like this, but currently the container height is not fixed.  I could try to hook every event that might change the size, figure out whether it's overflowing, and alter classes, but that seems like huge overkill just to get consistent behavior :(

Comment: @Coderer So do you mean with "the container height is not fixed"? In your question, there is a fixed `max-height` aswell.

Comment: Sorry, yes, in the example I fixed a small max-height to force overflow.  In the real application the container is sized with `vh`, but that isn't suitable to reproducing a simple example here.

Comment: @Coderer I edited my answer so you can use `vh` as `max-height`. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.  I always get nervous mixing pure CSS (max-height property) with computed values from JS (reading `$(window).height()` or similar), which is why I was trying to make a pure-CSS solution, but it looks like that might not be possible.

Comment: @Coderer I can't think of a CSS-only solution for this, sorry :/ But you can trust JS. It does a great job ;)

Answer (score 0):

Its default issue because scroll bar is always appear above the layer, but you can use an alternative to reduce this problem i.e

```css
 ul{

overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
max-height: 8em;
}
.border_sec{
 border: 2px solid grey;
border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="border_sec">
<ul>
<li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li>
<li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not a nice way to solve it. I now looks like the scrollbar is no part of the element :o

Comment: lol...this is the only way to solve the problem if you have other solution let me know, even you also used the same method. cheers !!

Comment: See my awnser... I did not use the same solution though.

Comment: lol... yes your answer is little bit different just used margin:0; but it depends upon the requirement. but leave it :P ..

Comment: I just give the solution of the question not giving the answer for whether scrollbar is part of element or not .. but your answer is appropriate move on !! :)